# Есть ли суффикс -ал- в слове «карнавал»?

Tags: этимология, заимствования, морфемика, индоевропеистика

В слове "карнавал" "ал" - это заимствованый суффикс?

Comment: Задавайте по одному вопросу в каждом вопросе.

Answer (score 3):

Этимологические словари Фасмера, Семёнова, Шанского опровергают версию с суффиксом. Шанский, например, утверждает:

> Карнава́л. Заимств. в XVIII в. из франц. яз., где carnaval «карнавал»
>   < «масленица» < итал. carnevale, восходящего к лат. carnem levare
>   «лишить мяса» (carne leva «забери мясо»). Карнавал буквально —
>   «последний день перед постом».

Карнавал - вся основа является корнем.
https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BA/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB